# In an Anchor test script, how do I stop the default provider from signing a transaction?

Tags: anchor, signing

How do I stop the provider from signing the following transaction?

In the following, the default provider still signs the transaction, but I'd like it not to:

```
await prog.methods
      .func()
      .accounts({
        account: myKeypair.publicKey,
      })
      .signers([myKeypair])
      .rpc();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`rpc` call](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/ts/src/program/namespace/methods.ts#L149) makes use of the Provider's [`sendAndConfirm` method](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/ts/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts#L29) which unconditionally [makes the wallet the fee payer](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/ts/src/provider.ts#L135), and [signs with the wallet](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/ts/src/provider.ts#L140).

I see two ways forward:

1. Implement your own Provider (`Provider` is an interface) with a `sendAndConfirm` that introduces an option for instance.
2. Do not use `.rpc()` from the `method` builder, but instead the `.transaction()`, and send the resulting tx manually using `@solana/web3.js`. E.g.:

```
const tx = await prog.methods
  .func()
  .accounts({ account: myKeypair.publicKey })
  .signers([myKeypair])
  .transaction();
await sendAndConfirmTransaction(prog.provider.connection, tx, [myKeypair])
```

Answer (score 0):

To sign a Solana transaction with a custom wallet using anchor typescript client you need to call `signer` method and provide the same keypair explicitly in `accounts` methods:

```
const myKeypair = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate()
await prog.methods
  .func()
  .accounts({
    payer: myKeypair.publicKey,
  })
  .signers([myKeypair])
  .rpc()
```

`payer` key in the `accounts` call argument must have the same name as the account that signs the `func` instruction.

If you are getting "unknown signer" error, make sure that you provided correct name of the signer account in the `account` method.

@man0s answer is valid option to sign an anchor transaction with custom keypair but you are loosing cool achor utility like handling errors with proper logs.

Answer (score 0):

We mock this using a mock user like so:

```
export type mockUser = {
  wallet: Keypair;
  /** A program that uses the user's wallet */
  userProgram: Program<OurProgram> | undefined;
};

export const getUserProgram = (
  program: Program<OurProgram>,
  userWallet: Keypair
) => {
  const userProgram = new Program(
    program.idl,
    program.programId,
    new AnchorProvider(program.provider.connection, new Wallet(userWallet), {})
  );
  return userProgram;
};
```

Once you initialize the wallet/program, you can send txes as your mock user using:

`await someUser.userProgram.provider.sendAndConfirm(tx);`

Now the tx is signed by the user's wallet without having to add the user as a signer, just like a tx on the front end would typically be.